# Svelte Actions Are Not Working With Non-Svelte JavaScript Libraries

Tags: javascript, carousel, svelte

I am having a list of blog cards which I have converted to a carousel using [Splide](https://splidejs.com/). Whenever I change to another page, I want to remove the existing Splide object. I want to use Svelte actions to achieve this but am unable to do it.

```html
<script>
  const splideAction = async (node, props)=>{
    
        const module = await import("@splidejs/splide");
        const Splide = module.default;
        const splide_css = await import("@splidejs/splide/dist/css/splide.min.css");
        const carousel = new Splide(".splide",{
        perPage:3,
        type:"loop",
        rewind: true,
        permove: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        breakpoints: {
            750: {
                perPage: 1
            },
            800:{
                perPage: 2
            }
        }
    }).mount();
        return {
            updated(){
                carousel.update();
                console.log("Updated")
            },
            destroy(){
                carousel.destroy();
                console.log("destroy")
            }
        }
    }
</script>


<div class="splide" use:splideAction>
                    <div class="splide__track" >
                        <div class="splide__list" >
                            {#each [...metadata.related_articles] as article (article.id)}
                            <div  class="splide__slide flex"><Card 
                            title = "{article.title}"
                            date = "{article.date}"
                            slug = "{article.slug}"
                            category= "{article.category}"
                            image = "{article.image}"/></div>
                                        
                        {/each} 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        
                </div>
```

When I click the card to another blog posts, I generates a new Carousel and the Old one is still there, How do I remove it destroy

Comment: Please provide a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.43.1) with your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. I would import the Splide module synchronously in your component instead of a dynamic import, so it is ready as soon as the component is rendered.
2. I'm not sure if asynchronously importing the CSS will work like that -- it may depend on your bundler setup. Either way, I would import it outside of the action, either by bundling it with the rest of your CSS or via CDN. In my example below, I load it from CDN using `<svelte:head>`.
3. I don't see an "updated" function in [Splide's API](https://splidejs.com/guides/apis/), so I'm not sure what `carousel.update()` would do. I don't think you need to return an "update" method from your action anyway, since your action isn't taking any parameters. The [update method](https://svelte.dev/docs#use_action) is meant to react to your action's parameters changing.
4. You're incorrectly storing a reference to the carousel -- you're storing a reference to the return value of `mount`, not the constructor. Because of this, `destroy` is being called on the wrong variable. Try something like this:

```js
const carousel = new Splide();
carousel.mount();
```

While your question is missing some context, the following component seems to work. I simplified the template since I don't have access to the article data. You can view it live in the [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/420ca57725164c338438e7b162db7bf7?version=3.43.1). I added a button to remove the component so you can see the carousel get destroyed.

```svelte
<script>
    import Splide from '@splidejs/splide';
    
    function carousel(node) {
        const splide = new Splide(node, {
                perPage: 3,
                type: "loop",
                rewind: true,
                permove: 1,
                autoplay: true,
                breakpoints: {
                    750: {
                        perPage: 1
                    },
                    800: {
                        perPage: 2
                    }
                }
        });
        splide.mount();
        
        return {
            destroy: () => {
                splide.destroy();
                console.log('destroyed');
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@3.0.9/dist/css/splide.min.css">
</svelte:head>

<div class="splide" use:carousel>
  <div class="splide__track">
        <ul class="splide__list">
            <li class="splide__slide">Slide 01</li>
            <li class="splide__slide">Slide 02</li>
            <li class="splide__slide">Slide 03</li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
    li {
        height: 300px;
        background: lightblue;
    }
</style>
```